# Find sibling views of class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a

```
  class Fancy:UIButton
```

and I want to find all the sibling views which are the same class.

I do this

```
for v:UIView in superview!.subviews
    {
    if v.isKindOfClass(Fancy)
        {
        // you may want... if (v==self) continue
        print("found one")
        (v as! Fancy).someProperty = 7
        (v as! Fancy).someCall()
        }
    }
```

it seems to work reliably in testing (no siblings, many, etc)

But there's a lot of "!" in there.

Is this the right way in Swift?

---

BTW here's a cool way to do it with extensions based on the great answers below

[Pass in a type to a generic Swift extension, or ideally infer it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240091/pass-in-a-type-to-a-generic-swift-extension)

Comment: Force-unwrapping is dangerous, and should be avoided.. If it fails, you crash. Your inner force-unwrapping `(v as! Fancy)` is save, but inelegant.

Comment: Hi @DuncanC, you're pretty sure it is safe??  (Inelegant we can deal with later :) )

Comment: The inner part is force down-casting, not force-unwrapping. I misspoke. And yes, it's safe, since you have it inside an if statement that checks the class of v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
for v in superview!.subviews
{
    if let f = v as? Fancy{
        print("found one")
        f.someProperty = 7
        f.someCall()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `for v in superview?.subviews ?? []` to get rid of the last `!`.

Comment: Also `if let f = v as? Fancy where f != self` if you want to skip `self`.

Comment: I feel this is the most straightforward, not-too-concise, not-too-wordy Swift-idiom answer. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 6):

What about using *functional programming*?

```
self.superview?
    .subviews
    .flatMap { $0 as? Fancy }
    .filter { $0 != self }
    .forEach { fancy in
        fancy.someProperty = 4
        fancy.someMethod()
    }
```

Comment: This answer is my favorite. (voted.) I need to teach myself to think in functional programming style.

Comment: @DuncanC: Thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: makes a nice extension!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240091/pass-in-a-type-to-a-generic-swift-extension

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
if let views = superview?.subviews
{
  for aView in views
  {
    if let fancyView = aView as? Fancy
    {
      fancyView.someProperty = 7
      fancyView.someCall()
    }
  }
}
```

@RobMayoff has a good point about excluding self. The code really should be:

```
if let views = superview?.subviews
{
  for aView in views
  {
    if let fancyView = aView as? Fancy where fancyView != self
    {
      fancyView.someProperty = 7
      fancyView.someCall()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I like the @appzYourLife's functional version, but you should accept *one* of them.

Comment: it's a great pity one can't write, as it were:  `for aView as? Fancy in views`

Comment: So you want a for loop with an 'as?' cast to do an implicit filter? That would be handy.

Comment: right!  that would indeed be neat.  i find the extension approach (see link below) to lead to very tidy code.  the "inferred or specified" thing is amazing

Comment: @JoeBlow "see link below." What link?

Comment: I meant this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240091/pass-in-a-type-to-a-generic-swift-extension cheers