# Pass in a type to a generic Swift extension, or ideally infer it

Tags: ios, swift, generics, functional-programming, swift-extensions

Say you have

```
 class Fancy:UIView
```

you want to find all sibling `Fancy` views.  [No problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37232743/294884)...

```
    for v:UIView in superview!.subviews
        {
        if let f = v as? Fancy
            { f.hungry = false }
        }
```

So, try an extension,

```
public extension UIView
    {
    internal func fancySiblings()->([Fancy])
        {
            return (self.superview!
                .subviews
                .filter { $0 != self }
                .flatMap { $0 as? Fancy }
                )
        }
    }
```

Awesome, you can now

```
    for f:Fancy in self.fancySiblings()
        { f.hungry = false }
```

Fantastic.

But,

## How to generalize that extension to work with any UIView subtype?

## Ideally, can the extension *infer the type*, even? As well as taking a type?

So, something like ...

```
public extension UIView
    {
    internal func siblings<T>( something T )->([T])
        {
            return (self.superview!
                .subviews
                .filter { $0 != self }
                .flatMap { $0 as? T }
                )
        }
```

and then you could call it something like this ...

```
    for f in self.siblings(Fancy)
    for p in self.siblings(Prancy)
    for b in self.siblings(UIButton)
```

How can you "tell" a generic extension the type to use, like that??

It seems you can "infer it backwards",

```
public extension UIView
    {
    internal func incredible<T>()->([T])
        {
        return (self.superview!
         .subviews
         .filter { $0 != self }
         .flatMap { $0 as? T }
         )
        }


    for f:Fancy in self.incredible()

    for p:Prancy in self.incredible()
```

Which is amazing but doesn't work the other way.

You can even...

```
    self.siblings().forEach{
        (f:Fancy) in
        d.hasRingOn = false
        }
```

So I would still like to know how to "pass in" a type something like `for f in self.siblings(Fancy)` and, ideally, even infer it also.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216240/generic-function-taking-a-type-name-in-swift (If you don't think it answers your question, that's okay – but it's the same underlying problem).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply use the `.Type`:

```
internal func siblings<T>( something : T.Type)->([T]) {
    ...
}
```

Afterwards `for f in self.siblings(Fancy)` should work exactly as expected.

Full working example:

```
class Fancy : UIView {}

public extension UIView {
    internal func siblings<T>( _ : T.Type)->([T]) {
        return (self.superview!
            .subviews
            .filter { $0 != self }
            .flatMap { $0 as? T }
        )
    }
}

let superView = UIView()
let view = UIView()
superView.addSubview(view)
superView.addSubview(UIView())
superView.addSubview(Fancy())

print(view.siblings(Fancy))
```

Correctly outputs the one `Fancy` view!

---

To address the requested addition for optionally using the explicit type parameter or take effect of the type inference of the compiler. You can create a second method in the same extension

```
internal func siblings<T>()->([T]) {
    return siblings(T)
}
```

That way providing a explicit type parameter calls method one, omitting it will require you to make it inferable and will call the second function which in terms calls the first one internally.

---

**Or**, you can use the far more *swifty* way and make the explicit type argument an optional with default `nil`. That, remarkably, will force the inference in case of omitting the type argument:

```
// power extension, it provides both infered or stated typing
internal func siblings<T>(_ : T.Type? = nil) -> ([T]) {
    return (self.superview!
        .subviews
        .filter { $0 != self }
        .flatMap { $0 as? T }
        )
}
```

That will enable you to call the method either via

```
for f in self.siblings(Fancy)
```

or even

```
for f : Fancy in self.siblings()
```

Both will work while still only defining one function.

Comment: @JoeBlow yes you actually can. I just did not want to change more code than necessary ;)

Comment: @JoeBlow You could make the type argument an optional, with a default value of `nil` (`_: T.Type? = nil`). That'll let you call the method with or without a type. The standard inferring should work as normal.

Comment: @luk2302 You're not in a playground by any chance are you? Playgrounds are notoriously unstable ;) It's working fine for me in a full project.

Comment: @originaluser2 of course I am :D and I know that, still funny whenever it happens.

Comment: @JoeBlow I included a second method to address your request. But that should be it. No more further request please. We are drifting away from the original question.

Comment: "Swift. It allows you to spend an incredibly long time perfecting incredibly short code."  :)

Comment: Posted an answer without having to worry about passing a type at all with a short explanation of why it's not necessary

Answer (score 4):

Similar answer to what's been said previously, but a little more streamlined and without having to pass anything or iterate over the subviews more than once:

```
extension UIView {
    internal func siblings<T: UIView>() -> [T] {
        return superview?.subviews.flatMap {return ($0 == self) ? nil : ($0 as? T) } ?? []
    }
}
```

or my preference using optionals:

```
internal func siblings<T: UIView>() -> [T]? {
        return superview?.subviews.flatMap {return ($0 == self) ? nil : $0 as? T } 
}
```

Example Usage:

```
class ExampleView: UIView {

    func getMatchingSiblings(){
        let foundSiblings: [ExampleView] = siblings()
    }

    //or with the for loop in the question:
    for item: ExampleView in siblings() {

    }
}
```

When dealing with generics, you simply need one instance of the generic type in the signature of the method. So if you have either a parameter, or return type that uses the generic, you don't need to pass the type.

Comment: Also incredibly informative.  I clicked a bounty to this answer *as well*  - thanks again all !