# Can only return, not assign, Self?

Tags: swift, static-methods, instantiation

Consider [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200426/294884)

```
extension UIViewController
{
    class func make(sb: String, id: String) -> Self
    {
        return helper(sb:sb, id:id)
    }

    private class func helper<T>(sb: String,id: String) -> T
    {
        let s = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let c = s.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as! T
        return c
    }
}
```

that works fine, so

```
let s = SomeViewControllerClass.make( ... )
```

does in fact return the subclass "SomeViewControllerClass".  (Not just a UIViewController.)

That's all fine BUT,

say in `make` you want to do some setup:

```
    class func make(sb: String, id: String) -> Self
    {
        let h = helper(sb:sb, id:id)
        // some setup, m.view = blah etc
        return h
    }
```

in fact it appears you *cannot do that*.

You can only

```
        return helper(sb:sb, id:id)
```

you cannot

```
        let h = helper(sb:sb, id:id)
        return h
```

is there a solution?

Comment: Well, that is the "trick" in the referenced pattern. In `return helper(sb:sb, id:id)` the generic placeholder type `T` is inferred from `Self`. – You can always move additional setup into the helper method.

Comment: Or add a `T.Type` parameter to `helper`, such as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/q/37240091/2976878. Then just pass in `self` for that parameter and `T` will be inferred to be `Self`.

Comment: I see what you mean @MartinR, thanks ...

Comment: @Hamish - excellent idea >thumbs up emoji<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a solution. That's exactly what the `helper` function is doing.

Why don't you put the code into `helper`?

To invoke `helper`, which is a generic type, you have to specify the type somehow, e.g.

```
let h: Self = helper(...)
```

or

```
let h = helper(...) as Self
```

but neither of those expressions would actually accept `Self`. Therefore, you need to infer the type from the return value `-> Self`. That's why `return` is the only thing that works.

Also note that you can use a *second* helper function.

```
class func make(sb: String, id: String) -> Self {
    let instance = helper2(sb: sb, id: id)        
    return instance
}

class func helper2(sb: String, id: String) -> Self {
    return helper(sb:sb, id:id)
}
```

Comment: @JoeBlow It helps, see the example. `helper2` infers the generic type of `helper` and `make` can then use the type directly.

Comment: quite right guys, of course you just put setup code it in the "helper" function.  good one.

Comment: how are you @sulthan - say, there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187881 a question looking for a kind of canonical iOS answer!  cheers..