# UICollectionView AutoSizingCells weird jump/glitch on reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, autosize

I'm using `UICollectionView` with the *AutoSizingCells* feature.

**Issue 1**
When I use this method in conjunction with `estimatedItemSize` and try to call `reloadData()`, I can observe, how the cell's content is changed.

I.e. if I had two cells:

```
Cell1 - "Text1"
Cell2 - "AnotherCell"
```

For a second I can see this state:

```
Cell1 - "AnotherCell"
Cell2 - "Text1"
```

And then, it updates to the correct one:

```
Cell1 - "Updated Text"
Cell2 - "AnotherCell"
```

[Video: ReloadData](https://streamable.com/ajrsd)

**Issue 2**

When I try to reload only the selected cell, I see another bug: the whole collectionView jumps and quickly updates its size.

[Video: Reload Single Item](https://streamable.com/hei9o)

When not using *AutoSizingCells* at all, there are no issues with the cell reload.

The bug is reproducible even if I don't override `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`.

Is there any option to disable the animation with the *AutoSizingCells* enabled?

Comment: What is "Issue 1"? Isn't reloadData supposed to do just that?

Comment: @user770 Correct. The issue was related to the `UIButton, type system` animation

Comment: `Issue 1` hasn't been solved still, and it's the preferred way of updating the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues with weird jump/glitch on `reloadData()`.

The issue was fixed when I migrated my collection view to iOS 13 and new APIs:

- [Compositional Layout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/layouts)
- [Diffable Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/updating_collection_views_using_diffable_data_sources)

You can find sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231881/1136128