# Constraint not updated after using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I'm using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to make my size and height of the `collectionViewCell` but when I use this one, the constraint in the `cell` are not updated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: self.height)
}
```

So the delegate method set the correct size but element in the cell are cuted (not updated). My cell constraint are set in the storyboard.

Comment: can you add your autolayout code or show storyboard/xib screen layout

Comment: @SuhitPatil I can't but my constraint are set with leading / trailing / top. and proportional to the contentView for the height.

Comment: you can use self sizing cells for using dynamic heights for collection view cells https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187881/uicollectionview-full-width-cells-allow-autolayout-dynamic-height/44352072

Answer (score 1):

Without too much detail, I guess you may need:

`viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

> Called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout its subviews.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews

or

`layoutSubviews()`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

Comment: Where call `layoutSubviews()` ? Cause beginUpdate doesn't exist in collectionView