# UICollectionViewCell resize swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I read an item by QR, consume a service and with that information I fill the UICollectionView. The first time I do this, I have no problem

[image]

Then when the second time, I have this

[image]

The log is:

`Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-04-21 17:25:56.172441-0500 Franz Mayer[878:58894] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281b9d130 Franz_Mayer.InfoCollectionViewCell_:0x10441da00.width == 351   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281bf0370 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' Franz_Mayer.InfoCollectionViewCell_:0x10441da00.width == 1   (active)>"
)`

The cell is

```
class InfoCollectionViewCell_: UICollectionViewCell {
let lHeader: UILabel = {
    let uILabel = UILabel()
    uILabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    uILabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    uILabel.numberOfLines = 2
    uILabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return uILabel
}()
let lDescription: UILabel = {
    let uILabel = UILabel()
    uILabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    uILabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    uILabel.numberOfLines = 100
    uILabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return uILabel
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    awakeFromNib()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //let widthConstraint = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - (2 * 12)).isActive = true
    addSubview(lHeader)
    lHeader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    lHeader.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    lHeader.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    addSubview(lDescription)
    lDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lHeader.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    lDescription.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    lDescription.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    lDescription.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    /*let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    widthConstraint.constant = screenWidth - (2 * 12)*/
    let sizes = Sizes.instance()
    Utils.autoResizeFont(uiElementText: lHeader, size: sizes.LABEL_PAGE_MESSAGE, isBold: true)
    Utils.autoResizeFont(uiElementText: lDescription, size: sizes.LABEL_PAGE_MESSAGE, isBold: false)

}
}
```

In the viewDidLoad on my Viewcontroller:

```
collectionView!.register(InfoCollectionViewCell_.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InfoCollectionViewCell_")
    if let flowLayout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1,height: 1)
    }

    collectionView!.dataSource = self
```

And

```
datos = object.datos!
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.reloadData()
```

How can I solve this problem ? Because the first time is OK, but after that I have te problem, but if I scrolled de Collection, the view back the view corrects itself.

Comment: Can you check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116115/5086658

Comment: It works fine the first time, but second time when I change de list and I do the collectionView!.reloadData(), I have the problem as in the second image