# Building UICollectionViewLayout - customize size of a single item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Below is code that works in order to have one `sectionIndex` of a `UICollectionViewLayout` with a different width/height for each item in that section compared to other sections. My question is how to further change the width of the first item within this section:

```
myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: myFrame, collectionViewLayout: generateLayout())
```

.

```
func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int,
         layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

     return self.generateStoryLayout(forSection: sectionIndex)
    }
    return layout
}
```

.

```
func generateStoryLayout(forSection: Int) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    print("generate story layout for this section")

    var groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .absolute(180),
        heightDimension: .absolute(216))

    //taller row in section 1
    if forSection == 1 {
        groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
             widthDimension: .absolute(250),
             heightDimension: .absolute(300))
    }

    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuousGroupLeadingBoundary   //.groupPaging

    return section
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!

I am separately using a different `UICollectionView` which uses a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for its layout and the function `layout:sizeForItemAt:` is called for each item in that `UICollectionView` and I can determine their sizes there.

The custom `myCollectionView` doesn't call to this `layout:sizeForItemAt:`

The `ViewController` does conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a suggestion here and I saw it repeatedly on other similar threads that "estimate size" needs to be turned off to get `layout:sizeForItemAt:` to work - but `layout:sizeForItemAt:` is specific to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and isn't called by a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`

The solution here was actually to use estimated sizes. When telling the collection view cells to estimate the size, you're telling them to use the size of the content to determine the size of the cell.

My goal was to increase the width of the first cell in a certain section because the image in that cell was wider than the rest. By using a `.estimated widthDimension` the first cell automatically sized itself larger because of the wider image.

Thank you UICollectionView!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set **Estimate Size** is none?

**layout:sizeForItemAt:** would not call if **Estimate Size** is Automatic
[image]

Comment: layout:sizeForItemAt: seems to be specific to UICollectionViewFlowLayout, which I am not using here. I am now seeing that by setting an estimated instead of an actual width, the item adjusts to fit the width of the content within, which is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform your view controller to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` both in order to make this method work :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { }
```

You are using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` so you don't need `sizeForItemAt`:

Please have a look to these tutorials:

- https://cocoacasts.com/modern-performant-collection-views-with-swift-an-introduction-to-compositional-collection-view-layouts
- [UICollectionView, full width cells, allow autolayout dynamic height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187881/uicollectionview-full-width-cells-allow-autolayout-dynamic-height)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Comment: I do conform to both, but myCollectionView uses a custom UICollectionViewLayout and does not use UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: But Amit, if you **are** using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, but you want one or two cells only (ie depending on the data) to have a specific different size - is that even possible?