# UICollectionView inside of UICollectionView with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a similar layout to the App store. I have got one collection view that is vertical and inside of it each row is another collection view that is horizontal.

I am trying to use dynamic height so the cell can increase its height based on the content inside. However that never works, it only works when i use sizeForItemAt function to explicitly set it. I would like to also be able to control the width

I have looked at many previous questions such as: [UICollectionView, full width cells, allow autolayout dynamic height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187881/uicollectionview-full-width-cells-allow-autolayout-dynamic-height) however no answer worked for me.

I am really confused on what i am doing wrong.

```
import UIKit


class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        collectionView?.register(HorizontalCollectionView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HorizontalCollectionView.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    public override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    public override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HorizontalCollectionView.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HorizontalCollectionView {
            return cell
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

HorizontalCollectionView.swift

```
import UIKit

class HorizontalCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "HorizontalCollectionView"
    var cellSpancolumns: CGFloat?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented - Storyboards are not used.")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        return collectionView
    }()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]