# Width of UICollectionView doesn't change inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, storyboard

I have **UICollectionView** inside **UITableViewCell**. If I make the size of the CollectionviewCell as **custom** and provide fixed width then it works fine.

But if I make it **automatic** and assign size in the delegate then it doesn't work. It takes the default width i.e 50.

Can you please help me out?
Thanks

Code for changing size:

```
extension BeInspiredTVC : UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        

        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50, height: 224)
    }

}
```

I want a full width Collectionviewcell but I am getting like the image below.

[image]

Comment: can you show please what you need to achieve by images

Comment: Yes. Sure. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Please check the image in the question

Comment: may you add the code of changing the size

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: Check this, I think it will resolve your issue Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231881/14437411

Answer (score 0):

take collection view width constraint

next assign **self.contentView.frame.width** to that constraint in layoutsubsview  in tableview cell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the CollectionView width is fine, but the CollectionviewCell width is not changing if I make it automatic.