# Resize collectionView cell based on the UIImageView inside it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view and each it its cell should have their own height based on it the image inside it

here I get data and resize the image based on that

```
public func configure(with data: Scraper) {
    
    guard let imageURL = URL(string: data.imageURL) else { return }
    
    KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: imageURL) { [weak self] result in
        guard let this = self else { return }
        
        if let image = try? result.get().image {
            this.setImageHeight(image: image)
            this.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}


private func setImageHeight(image: UIImage) {
    let ratio = image.size.height/image.size.width
    imageViewHeight.constant = imageViewWidth * ratio
}
```

and image constraint

```
imageViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0)
imageViewHeight.isActive = true
```

It works well for most of the cell, but some of the cell are not resized until doing more scroll then, they are all fine.

is there any better way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Using dynamic height to achieve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187881/uicollectionview-full-width-cells-allow-autolayout-dynamic-height

Comment: I use dynamic height, and it works, but not in the very good performance

Comment: Dynamic height does nothing cause lake performance. Maybe your code somewhere causes that. And it solves this question problem