# Generic core data fetch request

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I am trying to create sort of a generic wrapper for simple core data fetches.

What I wanted to achieve, is, instead of writing multiple redundant methods that look like this:

```
func loadNSMOSubclass() -> [NSMOSubclass] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSMOSubclass> = NSMOSubclass.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let result = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return result
    }
    catch {
        return []
    }
}
```

I thought I could create a generic helper for that:

```
struct EntityLoader<T> where T: NSManagedObject {

   func loadEntity() -> [T] {
       let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()
       do {
           let mainContext = CoreDataState().mainContext
           let result = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
           return result
       }
       catch {
           return []
       }
    }
}
```

However, at that point the compiler has a weird error:

> Cannot convert value of type `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` to specified type `NSFetchRequest<T>`

where the suggested solution is even stranger, since everything compiles when I do a casting:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
```

That might be ugly, but I could live with that. However when I run this code I am getting a fatal error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error:
>   `<null>` is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

Am I doing something wrong, or are these just some Swift's constraints that are currently impossible to surpass?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738058/create-a-generic-swift-function-to-return-an-array-of-core-data-entities?rq=1

Comment: @matt pretty much the same error when I'm trying the solution from your link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem here is `fetchRequest()` is a auto-generated helper function and it's only available for your `NSManagedObject` sub classes. It's not available for your generic type. Therefore, instead of using that function you have to use it's implementation with your generic type like this,

replace this line,

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()
```

with this,

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))
```