# Generic class type as parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to pass a class type as a parameter to compare it to the items in my toolbar:

```
private func getButton<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> UIBarButtonItem? {
    guard let bItems = parent?.toolbarItems else { return nil }

    return bItems.index { $0.customView is type }.map { bItems[$0] }
}
```

Unfortunately it keeps saying `Use of undeclared type "type"`. I guess Xcode is giving the wrong error.

How can I pass the class type as a generic and compare it as in my example?

Comment: Replace it by `$0.customView is T`

Comment: Oh wow, so simple.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or `return bItems.first(where: { $0.customView is T } )`

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216240/generic-function-taking-a-type-name-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240091/pass-in-a-type-to-a-generic-swift-extension-or-ideally-infer-it.